# how to write function which returns the position of the number in the array?

Tags: arrays, function

I have just started leran about C++. And I have to do one exercise but I don't know how. Please help me.

I have to write the function which  returns the position of the number in the array,rate and size are pass to this function and the value of the expression|tab[i]_M| is the maximum, where M is the average of all the elements.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at the values in your array one by one. You can access the individual values like this:

```
yourarray[index]
```

The best way to do it is a loop. There are several loops available in C++. You can use the `for` loop for example. Inside of the loop you check if the value is the one you are looking for

```
for (int i = 0; ...
{
   if your array[i] == your value
```

If you found the value, break the loop and return the index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Returns the index of the first occurrence of a value in the array, or -1 if not found
int GetPositionInArray(int array[], int value) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++) {
        if (array[i] == value)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```